# Python: Distance to nearest neighbor in row of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [4, 10], 'col4': [1, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df:
      col1 col2 col3 col4
   0  1    3    4    1
   1  2    4    10   8
```

How can I find the distance to the nearest neighbor in each row for each column? i.e. distance of nearest neighbor for df[col1][0] is 0, since distance from 1 to 1 (df[col1][0] = 1 and df[col4][0] = 1) is 0

Comment: What's your expected output? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: df.drop(x.name, axis=1).subtract(x, 0).abs().min(1))

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     1     1     0
1     2     2     2     2
```